# Swipe screen to rotate camera

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am writing a 3D game for smartphone using Unity3D and have no idea on making camera rotation (First Person Perspective).

Making virtual joystick is too hard, so I decided to make camera rotate on screen swipe.

User swipe smartphone's screen and camera turns around.

Rotating works, but always starts from the same position.

Saving last position breaks all rotating (rotating is askew).

My code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Look : MonoBehaviour {

public float sensitivityX = 1F;
public float sensitivityY = 1F;

public float minimumX = -360F;
public float maximumX = 360F;

public float minimumY = -25F;
public float maximumY = 25F;

float rotationX = 0F;
float rotationY = 0F;

float oldRotationX = 0F;
float oldRotationY = 0F;

float lastX = 0F;
float lastY = 0F;

Quaternion originalRotation;

void Update ()
{
    if (Input.touches.Length > 0)
    {
        if(Input.touches[0].phase == TouchPhase.Began)
        {
            lastX = Input.touches[0].position.x;
            lastY = Input.touches[0].position.y;

            rotationX = transform.localEulerAngles.x;
            rotationY = transform.localEulerAngles.y;

            oldRotationX = rotationX;
            oldRotationY = rotationY;
        }

        if(Input.touches[0].phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
        {
            rotationX = (oldRotationX + (Input.touches[0].position.x - lastX)) * sensitivityX;
            rotationY = (oldRotationY + (Input.touches[0].position.y - lastY)) * sensitivityY;

            rotationX = ClampAngle (rotationX, minimumX, maximumX);
            rotationY = ClampAngle (rotationY, minimumY, maximumY);

            Quaternion xQuaternion = Quaternion.AngleAxis (rotationX, Vector3.up);
            Quaternion yQuaternion = Quaternion.AngleAxis (rotationY, -Vector3.right);

            transform.localRotation = originalRotation * xQuaternion * yQuaternion;
        }

        //this should make rotating from last position, but it
        //makes rotating incorrect (askew)
        //without code below rotating works, but on always
        //starts from the same position
        if(Input.touches[0].phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
        {
            originalRotation = transform.localRotation;
        }
    }
}

void Start ()
{
    if (rigidbody)
        rigidbody.freezeRotation = true;

    originalRotation = transform.localRotation;
}

public static float ClampAngle (float angle, float min, float max)
{
    if (angle < -360F)
        angle += 360F;
    if (angle > 360F)
        angle -= 360F;
    return Mathf.Clamp (angle, min, max);
}
}
```

Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [inputs](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.html), specifically the Touch positions. You can then apply a similar effect achieved in a [mouse look script](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/29741/mouse-look-script.html).

Essentially the code you want is:

```
rotationX += Input.touches[0].position.x * sensitivityX;
rotationY += Input.touches[0].position.y * sensitivityY

Quaternion xQuaternion = Quaternion.AngleAxis (rotationX, Vector3.up);
Quaternion yQuaternion = Quaternion.AngleAxis (rotationY, -Vector3.right);

transform.localRotation *= xQuaternion * yQuaternion;
```

Comment: I edited my question and added code. Can You help me? I described my problem specific.

Answer (score -1):

```
if(Input.touches.Length > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved){ 
  transform.Rotate(new Vector3(-Input.GetTouch(0).deltaPosition.y,Input.GetTouch(0).deltaPosition.x,0)*speed*Time.deltaTime);
  transform.rotation=Quaternion.Euler(transform.rotation.eulerAngles.x,transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y,0);
}
```