# I want to rotate the camera like Minecraft | Android

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to swipe and turn the camera.

I reproduced the Maincraft in Windwos with Character 's First Person Controll.And how do you implement it on Android?I use joystick for the movement, but I want to swipe the rotation of the camera.What should I do?

Comment: Someone posted a similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24221366/swipe-screen-to-rotate-camera?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unity is a multiplatform game engine but you can't expect to create one game and run it everywhere. FPC have a desktop implementation and it's not intended to be used for mobile device. If you are interested in Android development I suggest you to take a look at Unity's Android SDK.